# React Native2 not compile in release

Tags: reactjs, github, npm-install

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AyBi.png)

`npm run start` failed to compile. I know I must have mixed up the syntax or omitted something. Please take a look and tell me how to fix it. Here is the github link to the codes. Thanks.

https://github.com/ayeremascot/blogapp

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Please post text, not images of text.

Comment: That said, the error is quite clear, and is trivial to fix: read the error, look at the file in question, look at what you're importing, and look at your file name you're attempting to import.